# Is there preprocessing needed in ppscore regressional computation for time series data?

Tags: python

Do [ppscores](https://github.com/8080labs/ppscore) , which pose to be a effecient alternative to standard Pearson correlation, need some preprocessing?
Eg: For calculating beta of a stock vs index, we usually correlate the returns of the two. What would be a valid input incase of computing beta using ppscore, the returns or the price series?